# Unable to import Python module in Python script

Tags: python, import

I have a Python project having the following hierarchy:

```
- product_recommender_sys
  - data
    - dataset.csv
  - public
    - __init__.py
    - startup.py
  - src
    - __init__.py
    - recommender.py
```

I am trying to import the `recommender.py` module in `startup.py`.
Following is the code:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/user1/product_recommender_sys/src')
print sys.path
from product_recommender_sys.src import recommender
recommender.recommend()
```

I have included `__init__.py` file and added the respective folders to `sys.path`. Also, the same `import` statement works perfectly fine on the Python interpreter, but fails inside the script. How can I get the import to work inside the script?

Comment: Could you please format the tree better, it would make things a lot easier.

Comment: What if you use `sys.path.insert(0, '/home/user1/product_recommender_sys')` Since this is the root folder of the module.

Comment: @PaulRooney , I tried the root folder too. Doesnt make any difference.Throws the same error "ImportError: No module named product_recommender_sys.src"

Comment: Strange it fixed it for me.

Comment: Should I be using `__init__.py` file in both sub-directories?

Comment: Also,any specific permissions need to be granted to the files? I have set them all to `-rwxr-xr-x` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.
The startup.py module was not getting compiled since it was not being imported.

First compiling the script solves the problem.

```
python -m compileall product_recommender_sys/public/startup.py
```